# Add multiple domain access policy to AWS Elasticsearch Service (Static IP and Lambda ARN)

Tags: amazon-web-services, elasticsearch, aws-lambda, amazon-elasticsearch, aws-access-policy

After setting up AWS Elasticsearch, I installed Logstash and Kibana proxy on a static IP server, and added this domain access policy on ES and it's working fine:

```json
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Sid": "",
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Principal": {
        "AWS": "*"
      },
      "Action": "es:*",
      "Resource": "arn:aws:es:ap-southeast-1:323137313233:domain/sg-es-logs/*",
      "Condition": {
        "IpAddress": {
          "aws:SourceIp": [
            "192.192.192.192"
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Now I need to allow Lambda function to execute `es:ESHttpDelete` action on AWS ES, so I created the function with the existing role `service-role/Elasticsearch` then copied the relevent `ARN` from IAM Managment console to add it to AWS ES access policy, to come up with this:

```json
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Principal": {
        "AWS": [
          "arn:aws:iam:: 323137313233:role/service-role/Elasticsearch"
        ]
      },
      "Action": [
        "es:*"
      ],
      "Resource": "arn:aws:es:ap-southeast-1:323137313233:domain/sg-es-logs/*"
    }
  ]
}
```

The problem is on ES I should either choose domain access policy for Static IP or ARN but not both. When I tried to merge them manually not by using the console it didn't work. I checked AWS documentation but they didn't mention if is that possible or not.

Comment: FWIW, Amazon Developer Support is very good, but it costs you $30 a month.  I don't know the answer and as you said, the docs don't really talk about how to do what you want to do.

Comment: Your first policy has a prohibited Principal field. How did you ever get it to work?

Instead of specifying a Principal, try adding a second condition where you compare the Principal ARN

Answer (score 2):

You can add multiple policy statements inside the `Statement` array in the JSON format of policy. So, your final policy would be something like:

```js
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Sid": "",
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Principal": {
        "AWS": "*"
      },
      "Action": "es:*",
      "Resource": "arn:aws:es:ap-southeast-1:323137313233:domain/sg-es-logs/*",
      "Condition": {
        "IpAddress": {
          "aws:SourceIp": [
            "192.192.192.192"
          ]
        }
      }
    },
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Principal": {
        "AWS": [
          "arn:aws:iam:: 323137313233:role/service-role/Elasticsearch"
        ]
      },
      "Action": [
        "es:*"
      ],
      "Resource": "arn:aws:es:ap-southeast-1:323137313233:domain/sg-es-logs/*"
    }
  ]
}
```